# Apache to Nginx Migration issues with mcrypt and base_64_decode

Tags: php, nginx

I recently moved a website from Apache to Nginx and once moved following piece of code stop working properly. the output i get is now like below. not sure why and how to fix the issue

(** I have noticed the issue is coming from the base64_decode() function not working properly)

Output of following code is

**`y�   A�K�_7<�lrպ�;0E�lg�b�4function exists`**

and the code is as below

```
$text='eewJQQgTr0uUEl83PORsHxBy1bqdOzBF6gdsZ9BisTQ=';
if (function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) {
    echo $text = base64_decode( $text );
    echo $data=mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '43263fsfjhfklkkl898984hj', $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB )) );
    echo 'function exists';
}
else{
    $data =  base64_decode(base64_decode( $text ));
    echo 'function dont exists';
}
die();
```